# Overlaying a transparent background on an embedded video

Tags: html, css, video, overlay

I've a video which I've embedded in a fullwidth div panel. I'm trying to overlay a gradient on top of it, but I can't make it work. I've tried adjusting z-index, wrapping the video in another div, and - as below - adding an overlay class, but I must be missing something obvious.

Whatever I try, the video jumps back on top of the other panels (which end up falling behind it).

Would be so grateful for your help!

```
                <div class="videoContainer hide-for-small-only">
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                  <video autoplay loop muted>
                        <source src="<?=URL?>public/videos/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        <source src="<?=URL?>public/videos/vid.webm" type="video/webm">
                  </video>
                </div>
```

My css is:

```
.videoContainer 
{

  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  //padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;

  background-attachment: scroll;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.videoContainer video 
{
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.videoContainer overlay {
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0%;
  }
```

Comment: try creating a fiddle.

Comment: A codepen of the above looks like: http://codepen.io/simeonw/pen/waXYvr Jsfiddle didn't show anything.

Comment: .videoContainer overlay should be .videoContainer .overlay

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/36Lj4kxt/)

I used green overlay for the demo.

**CSS**

```
.videoContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    //padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.videoContainer video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.videoContainer .overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    background: green;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across this very same issue and eventually managed to get an aesthetically similar effect simply setting the video with `opacity:0.5` over a colored background.

```css
.vid-bg {
  opacity: 0.5; /* ! */
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color: green">
    <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop" class="vid-bg">
    <source src="http://inserthtml.com/demos/javascript/background-videos/flowers.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</body>
```